# Works in .NET, don't work in PHP? SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

EDIT:
I managed to get through this by asking the server developer to split the string into an array on his side. It works now.

Anyway, i never managed to know how to correctly pass an array to a .NET soap server.

---

i have a SOAP client in PHP that is not working. The server developer handled me a working .NET example. I paste here both. Am i missing something?

Regards

> PHP CODE

```
$res = new cResult;

//$oRequest = new InsertVenta; (throws the same error wether this is specified or not)

$pcAccesorios = new cACC_VENTA;

$oUSER = new cUSER;
$oUSER->LOGIN = "hidden"; 
$oUSER->PASS  = "hidden";
//$oUSER->ERROR = 0;

$oAVISO = new cVENTA;
$oAVISO->NOMBRE = str_pad($nombre, 150); 
$oAVISO->DIRECCION = str_pad($direccion, 250);       
$oAVISO->CP = str_pad($codpostal, 5);              
$oAVISO->POBLACION = str_pad($poblacion, 150);       
$oAVISO->PROVINCIA = str_pad($provincia, 75);      
$oAVISO->PERS_CONTACTO = str_pad($pers_contacto, 150);   
$oAVISO->TFNS_CONTACTO = str_pad($telefono, 50);   
$oAVISO->EMAIL = str_pad($email, 75); 
$oAVISO->NIF = str_pad($nifcif, 10);
$oAVISO->ERROR = 0;
//$oAVISO->HasError = 0;
//$oAVISO->$ID_ORDEN = 0;


$oRequest->oUSER = $oUSER;       
$oRequest->oAVISO = $oAVISO;

$maxindex = count($listacompra);
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $maxindex; $i++) {
    $array_de_2 = explode(" ", $listacompra[$i]);

    $pcAccesorios->REFERENCIA = $array_de_2[1];
    $pcAccesorios->UNIDADES = $array_de_2[0];

    $oRequest->oACC[$i] = $pcAccesorios;
}

//$oRequest->oACC = $oACC; 
//var_dump($oRequest);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wdsladdress, array("trace" => 1,"exceptions"=>0));
    //print $client->__getTypes();
    //var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    //print "conectado      ";
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo '', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 die();
}

try {             
    //$res=$client->INSERT_VENTA($oUSER, $oAVISO, $oACC);

    $res=$client->INSERT_VENTA($oRequest);
    //$client->__getLastRequest();
    //$res->INSERT_VENTAResult;
    $ID_ORDEN=(string)$res->INSERT_VENTAResult->ID_ORDEN;
    var_dump($ID_ORDEN);
    print var_dump($res);                            
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo '',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
die();
}
```

> .NET CODE

```
Dim oAVISO As New WS_TSG.cVENTA
oAVISO.CP = "24400"
oAVISO.DIRECCION = "Mi direccion "
oAVISO.EMAIL = "email@servidor.com "
'oAVISO.ID_ORDEN =
oAVISO.NIF = "A12345678 "
oAVISO.NOMBRE = "Mi nombre "
oAVISO.PERS_CONTACTO = "Anonimo Nadie "
oAVISO.POBLACION = "Vega de la esquina "
oAVISO.PROVINCIA = "Leon "
oAVISO.TFNS_CONTACTO = "987343434 "

Dim oACC As New WS_TSG.ArrayOfCACC_VENTA
Dim oACC_VENTA As New WS_TSG.cACC_VENTA

oACC_VENTA.REFERENCIA = "KITHDTV72"
oACC_VENTA.UNIDADES = "1"
oACC.Add(oACC_VENTA)
oACC_VENTA.REFERENCIA = "USBTV82"
oACC_VENTA.UNIDADES = "2"
oACC.Add(oACC_VENTA)
oACC_VENTA.REFERENCIA = "ACDCTV425"
oACC_VENTA.UNIDADES = "1"
oACC.Add(oACC_VENTA)

oAVISO = WS.INSERT_VENTA(oUSER, oAVISO, oACC)
```

The error is:

> Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML
>   document (2, 280). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: check the generated documents, possible namespace issue

Comment: I've come to thing the problem is "how" i pass the accesories array, i've tried:

- Withing the args as an array: i.e.: oRequest->oACC[] <- this being an array.
- As an object, containing an array: i.e.: oRequest->oACC[] = ArrayOfAccesories

Answer (score 1):

I already have some issues with soap communication between .net and PHP.

For me the solution was to use Zend Soap and the specific DotNet client class:

first at all, use ZendSoap component (it's simply a wrapper around the Soap php's extension wich provide some usefull function and configuration stuff) : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html

the specific client\DotNet class:

```
<?php
use Zend\Soap\Client;
$client = new Client\DotNet($wdsladdress, array("trace" => 1,"exceptions"=>0));
$client->method();
```

Api doc : http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Soap.Client.DotNet.html

Comment: I already have some other functions working on that server, this is the only one i'm having troubles with. This is also the only one in wich i have to put an array into. I'm sure Zend improves the overall soap experience, but i'd like to keep the coherence within the project. I'm sure this can be solved. Anyway thanks, i didnt knew about Zend (n00b here), i'll give it a read.

Comment: Maybe this comment can help you:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#89308

Comment: thank you all on the input. in the end we had to make it work in a different way. Im considering switching to a framework now (Yii) since it seems "cleaner" to work with this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `\Zend\Soap\Client\DotNet` you might need to

1. use setOptions (instead passing options as second argument )
2. Pass `authentication` and other stuff in the `$options`of your constructor
3. specify a fake wsdl and load it in `\Zend\Soap\Client\Common` that will be passed as first parameter.

   ```
   $url = 'https://WSURL.com/Something.asmx?wsdl';
   $options = [
       'authentication' => 'ntlm',
       'login' => 'YOURLOGIN',
       'password' => 'YOURPASS',
       'wsdl' =>  $url',
   ];
   $soap = new \Zend\Soap\Client\DotNet($url);
   $soap->setOptions($options);
   $uselessClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client\Common('anystring', 'FakeWsdl.xml', []);
   $response = $soap->_doRequest($uselessClient, $fullXMLRequestBody, $urlOfRealWsdl, 'SoapMethodWeWantToUse', SOAP_1_1 );
   ```

Be aware to replace `$urlOfRealWsdl`, `$fullXMLRequestBody`and `SoapMethodWeWantToUse`.

All of these can be found when accessing your  ws url in a browser (without ?wsdl) and clicking on the desired method.